# Perl - itinerate through a file

Tags: perl, loops

I have a file like it:

```
>Sequence1
AAAAASSSSSSSSDDD
BBHSHSJSKJSKJSSS
SJKÑLSDJFSLSLJKS
>Sequence2
AAASSSSSSSSSSDDW
```

up to 55 sequences.

I need to save each sequence (for instance `AAAAASSSSSSSSDDD` into a different variable. So I should create as many variables as sequences has my file.

Until now I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    if (/^>/) {
        $count++;
        next;
    }
}

print $count;     #It prints 55.
```

How should I continue? I am lost creating dynamically variables...

Comment: There's probably a nice module for fasta files for you to use if you search CPAN. This is a rather common question here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a hash like this:

```
my %sequences;
my $key;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(\w+)/) {
        $key = $1;
        next;
    }
    $sequences{$key} = $_;
}
```

The last sentence could be:

```
    $sequences{$key} .= $_;
```

You may also use a hash of array:

```
my %sequences;
my $key;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(\w+)/) {
        $key = $1;
        next;
    }
    push @{$sequences{$key}}, $_;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean `(\w+)`?

Comment: @user2886545 `\w` is a character class that includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, the parentheses captures the string to `$1`.

Comment: What if my sequence is splited by break lines?

Comment: @user2886545: Sorry I don't get you. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: I've modified my post, look at the first sequence.

Comment: @user2886545: OK. Do you want to keep the line break between part of a sequence? If so, just remove the `chomp;` at the begining of the while loop and use the second version `$sequences{$key} .= $_;`

Comment: But `$sequences{$key} .= $_;` would append all sequences together, wouldn't it? And I want sequence1 separated from the sequence2...

Comment: @user2886545: So use the hash of array as I edited in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The tool you need for the job is called *array*. See [perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata) for documentation.

```
my $count = -1;
my @sequences;

while (<>) {
    if (/^>/) {
        $count++;
    } else {
        $sequences[$count] .= $_;
    }
}
```

Do you use [Bio::Perl](http://p3rl.org/Bio%3a%3aPerl)?

Comment: That Bio::Perl looks really nice. I was always hesitant to link people who show a rather limited understanding of Perl to BioPerl.org as it does look kind of intimidating.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @sequences;
while (<>) {
    if (/^>/) {
        $count++;
        next;
    }
    else
    {
        chomp $_;
        push @sequences, $_;
    }
}

print $count;     #It prints 55.
```

Now you have an array with all your sequences in it, ordered and all.

Comment: What if my sequence is splited by break lines?

Comment: As i wrote it, that would mean the sequence would get split into two but at least the `$count` would still be correct. ^^ If that is a problem, make sure to use Chorobas version as `.=` means append to the string. Note that in their version, all newlines are preserved. If you do not want a newline after every sequence and in the middle of everyone that was split beforehand, insert `chomp $_;` in their answer right after the `else`. Or just follow the link to Bio::Perl and use that.